# ng2-google-charts and loader - bad version error

Tags: angular, charts, google-visualization, node-modules

I have some charts in my project that seems to be work well. In really, when I try to refresh the page in internet explorer, I found this error:

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Bad version: 45.2

that refers to my charts and the plugin get broken. This is the versione that I found in chart.service.loader but if I try to change it with a previous release I have the same error.

Can you help me?

This is my situation:

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.3
Node: 8.9.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.3
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.3
@schematics/angular               0.6.3
@schematics/update                0.6.3
rxjs                              6.2.0
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

Ng2-google-chart has the 3.3 version atm, I just changed it from 3.4. 
Angular was not updated, I just updated it too but nothing changed.

Thanks

Comment: Shared below...this is the code auto implemented bu ng2-google-charts

Comment: not sure i can help, try replacing `'45.2'` with `'current'`

Comment: I tried this way too, but still not working well :(

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter, LOCALE_ID, Inject } from '@angular/core';
var GoogleChartsLoaderService = /** @class */ (function () {
    function GoogleChartsLoaderService(localeId) {
        this.chartPackage = {
            AnnotationChart: 'annotationchart',
            AreaChart: 'corechart',
            Bar: 'bar',
            BarChart: 'corechart',
            BubbleChart: 'corechart',
            Calendar: 'calendar',
            CandlestickChart: 'corechart',
            ColumnChart: 'corechart',
            ComboChart: 'corechart',
            PieChart: 'corechart',
            Gantt: 'gantt',
            Gauge: 'gauge',
            GeoChart: 'geochart',
            Histogram: 'corechart',
            Line: 'line',
            LineChart: 'corechart',
            Map: 'map',
            OrgChart: 'orgchart',
            Sankey: 'sankey',
            Scatter: 'scatter',
            ScatterChart: 'corechart',
            SteppedAreaChart: 'corechart',
            Table: 'table',
            Timeline: 'timeline',
            TreeMap: 'treemap',
            WordTree: 'wordtree'
        };
        this.googleScriptLoadingNotifier = new EventEmitter();
        this.googleScriptIsLoading = false;
        this.localeId = localeId;
    }
    GoogleChartsLoaderService.prototype.load = function (chartType, apiKey) {
        var _this = this;
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            if (resolve === void 0) { resolve = Function.prototype; }
            if (reject === void 0) { reject = Function.prototype; }
            _this.loadGoogleChartsScript().then(function () {
                var initializer = {
                    packages: [_this.chartPackage[chartType]],
                    language: _this.localeId,
                    callback: resolve
                };
                if (apiKey) {
                    initializer.mapsApiKey = apiKey;
                }
                google.charts.load('45.2', initializer);
            }).catch(function (err) { return reject(); });
        });
    };
    GoogleChartsLoaderService.prototype.loadGoogleChartsScript = function () {
        var _this = this;
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            if (resolve === void 0) { resolve = Function.prototype; }
            if (reject === void 0) { reject = Function.prototype; }
            if (typeof google !== 'undefined' && google.charts) {
                resolve();
            }
            else if (!_this.googleScriptIsLoading) {
                _this.googleScriptIsLoading = true;
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.type = 'text/javascript';
                script.src = 'https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js';
                script.async = true;
                script.defer = true;
                script.onload = function () {
                    _this.googleScriptIsLoading = false;
                    _this.googleScriptLoadingNotifier.emit(true);
                    resolve();
                };
                script.onerror = function () {
                    _this.googleScriptIsLoading = false;
                    _this.googleScriptLoadingNotifier.emit(false);
                    reject();
                };
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
            }
            else {
                _this.googleScriptLoadingNotifier.subscribe(function (loaded) {
                    if (loaded) {
                        resolve();
                    }
                    else {
                        reject();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    };
    GoogleChartsLoaderService.decorators = [
        { type: Injectable },
    ];
    /** @nocollapse */
    GoogleChartsLoaderService.ctorParameters = function () { return [
        { type: undefined, decorators: [{ type: Inject, args: [LOCALE_ID,] },] },
    ]; };
    return GoogleChartsLoaderService;
}());
export { GoogleChartsLoaderService };
```

Comment: Adding some explanations about what you did would help to understand the answer